# mailcatcher cannot catch email form PHP

Tags: php, ubuntu, vagrant

I install vagrant dev machine with ubuntu and mailcatcher

```
  sudo apt-get install ruby rubygems ruby-dev sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev
  sudo gem install mailcatcher
```

the i run

```
mailcatcher --http-ip=0.0.0.0
```

in php.ini I have `sendmail_path = "/usr/bin/env /usr/local/bin/catchmail"`

the mailcather is running but in php skript i test it with

```
<?php
// The message
$message = "Line 1\r\nLine 2\r\nLine 3";

// In case any of our lines are larger than 70 characters, we should use wordwrap()
$message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");

// Send
$sent = mail('caffeinated@example.com', 'My Subject', $message);

?>
```

the mail isnt catch in Mailcatcher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem solved in php mail function must be set from header

```
$message = "Line 1\r\nLine 2\r\nLine 3";


$message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");


$sent = mail('caffeinated@example.com', 'My Subject', $message, null,'-fwebmaster@example.com');
```

Answer (score 2):

You most likely have smtp_port set to port 25, you should change it in php.ini to 1025, so it will hit Mailcatcher instead of your regular MTA. If you do that, then you don't have to specify the extra parameters.